# Can I start fiddler from C#?

Tags: c#, fiddler

I'm trying to build a C# application, which uses Fiddler. I saw in the documentation somewhere, that there is supposed to be a function Fiddler.Application.Start or something like that. However, I can't find it. I'd prefer not to write a fiddler extension, because I think it will be more powerful to integrate fiddler into my app. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Please note: FiddlerCore is currently undergoing a limited, Microsoft-Internal alpha. At present, there is no timeline for a broader release." http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore

So, it appears there is no way to get FiddlerCore unless you work for Microsoft.

Answer (score 10):

You're really asking about [FiddlerCore](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore), which is different than Fiddler. You cannot replicate FiddlerCore by simply wrapping Fiddler.exe.

If you want to automate Fiddler, simply launch it with Process.Start. You can send commands to the FiddlerScript engine using the [ExecAction executable](http://www.fiddlerbook.com/Fiddler/dev/#automation).

Incidentally, neither Fiddler nor FiddlerCore is a COM object.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` on the fiddler EXE, no?

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore-demo) what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to use Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup but it doesn't show up in the COM object.

Comment: Try one of the following:
- Adding a reference to Fiddler.exe directly
- Registering fiddler.exe for COM-interop (regsvr32 Fiddler.exe)
- Generating .NET bindings for COM stuff (after regsvr32, do tlbimp Fiddler.exe /out:.NETFiddlerBindings.dll)

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee that will break.